# Difference between System.DateTime.Now and System.DateTime.Today

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

Can anyone explain the difference between `System.DateTime.Now` and `System.DateTime.Today` in C#.NET? Pros and cons of each if possible.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` returns a `DateTime` value that consists of the local date and time of the computer where the code is running.  It has `DateTimeKind.Local` assigned to its `Kind` property.  It is equivalent to calling  any of the following:

- `DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()`
- `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.LocalDateTime`
- `DateTimeOffset.Now.LocalDateTime`
- `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local)`
- `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local)`

`DateTime.Today` returns a `DateTime` value that has the same year, month, and day components as any of the above expressions, but with the time components set to zero.  It also has `DateTimeKind.Local` in its `Kind` property.  It is equivalent to any of the following:

- `DateTime.Now.Date`
- `DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().Date`
- `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.LocalDateTime.Date`
- `DateTimeOffset.Now.LocalDateTime.Date`
- `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local).Date`
- `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local).Date`

Note that internally, the system clock is in terms of UTC, so when you call `DateTime.Now` it first gets the UTC time (via the [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397.aspx) function in the Win32 API) and then it converts the value to the local time zone.  (Therefore `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()` is more expensive than `DateTime.UtcNow`.)

Also note that `DateTimeOffset.Now.DateTime` will have similar values to `DateTime.Now`, but it will have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` rather than `DateTimeKind.Local` - which could lead to other errors depending on what you do with it.

So, the simple answer is that `DateTime.Today` is equivalent to `DateTime.Now.Date`.
**But IMHO - You shouldn't use either one of these, or any of the above equivalents.**

When you ask for `DateTime.Now`, you are asking for the value of the local calendar clock of the computer that the code is running on.  But what you get back does not have any information about that clock!  The best that you get is that `DateTime.Now.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local`.  But whose local is it?  That information gets lost as soon as you do anything with the value, such as store it in a database, display it on screen, or transmit it using a web service.

If your local time zone follows any daylight savings rules, you do not get that information back from `DateTime.Now`.  In ambiguous times, such as during a "fall-back" transition, you won't know which of the two possible moments correspond to the value you retrieved with `DateTime.Now`.  For example, say your system time zone is set to `Mountain Time (US & Canada)` and you ask for `DateTime.Now` in the early hours of November 3rd, 2013.  What does the result `2013-11-03 01:00:00` mean?  There are two moments of instantaneous time represented by this same calendar datetime.  If I were to send this value to someone else, they would have no idea which one I meant.  Especially if they are in a time zone where the rules are different.

The best thing you could do would be to use `DateTimeOffset` instead:

```
// This will always be unambiguous.
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

Now for the same scenario I described above, I get the value `2013-11-03 01:00:00 -0600` before the transition, or `2013-11-03 01:00:00 -0700` after the transition.  Anyone looking at these values can tell what I meant.

I wrote a blog post on this very subject.  Please read - [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Also, there are some places in this world (such as Brazil) where the "spring-forward" transition happens exactly at Midnight.  The clocks go from 23:59 to 01:00.  This means that the value you get for `DateTime.Today` on that date, *does not exist!*  Even if you use `DateTimeOffset.Now.Date`, you are getting the same result, and you still have this problem.  It is because traditionally, there has been no such thing as a `Date` object in .Net.  So regardless of how you obtain the value, once you strip off the time - you have to remember that it doesn't really represent "midnight", even though that's the value you're working with.

If you really want a fully correct solution to this problem, the best approach is to use [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org).  The `LocalDate` class properly represents a date without a time.  You can get the current date for any time zone, including the local system time zone:

```
using NodaTime;
...

Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;

DateTimeZone zone1 = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
LocalDate todayInTheSystemZone = now.InZone(zone1).Date;

DateTimeZone zone2 = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
LocalDate todayInTheOtherZone = now.InZone(zone2).Date;
```

If you don't want to use Noda Time, there is now another option.  I've contributed an implementation of a date-only object to the [.Net CoreFX Lab](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab) project.  You can find the `System.Time` package object in their MyGet feed.  Once added to your project, you will find you can do any of the following:

```
using System;
...

Date localDate = Date.Today;

Date utcDate = Date.UtcToday;

Date tzSpecificDate = Date.TodayInTimeZone(anyTimeZoneInfoObject);
```

Comment: What about the use of `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTimeOffset.Now`?

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow` is acceptable if you can convey in your application or spec that the value is in UTC.  (I like to actually call the field or property something like `MyDateUtc` instead of just `MyDate` - but that's just icing on the cake.)   If you can't convey it in the spec or field name, then `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` can be used to ensure the zero offset gets conveyed with the date and time values.

Comment: They are not equal.  Today has the time as 00:00:00.

Comment: @JamesWilkins - Not sure what you're getting at.  So does `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Comment: @MattJohnson The question is asking the difference between DateTime.Today and DateTime.Now, not DateTime.Today and DateTime.Now.Date.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - You're right, I never *directly* answered the question in the way that it was originally asked.  I've updated my answer.  Does that help?

Comment: @MattJohnson Yup!  I just wanted to point it out since it explains some of the confusion in the comments and hopefully your edit should steer people in the right direction in the future.

Answer (score 94):

Time. `.Now` includes the 09:23:12 or whatever; `.Today` is the date-part only  (at 00:00:00 on that day).

So use `.Now` if you want to include the time, and `.Today` if you just want the date!

`.Today` is essentially the same as `.Now.Date`

Comment: ... and use `UtcNow` unless you *really* want the system local time zone. (In particular, on a web app that's almost always the wrong choice.)

Answer (score 25):

The `DateTime.Now` property returns the current date and time, for example `2011-07-01 10:09.45310`.

The `DateTime.Today` property returns the current date with the time compnents set to zero, for example `2011-07-01 00:00.00000`.

The `DateTime.Today` property actually is implemented to return `DateTime.Now.Date`:

```
public static DateTime Today {
  get {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    return now.Date;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

[DateTime.Today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) represents the current system date with the time part set to 00:00:00

and

[DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) represents the current system date and time

Comment: just an observation... the 1.1 documentation is far less detailed than then 4.0 documentation; it is perhaps better to link to vLatest?

Comment: @megaperlz: You are now linking to 4.0 rather than vLatest.  VLatest links can be made by deleting the `(v=VS.100)`.

Answer (score 6):

I thought of Adding these links -

- [A brief History of DateTime - By Anthony Moore by BCL team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/18/a-brief-history-of-datetime-anthony-moore.aspx)
- [Choosing between Datetime and DateTime Offset - by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx)
- [Do not forget SQL server 2008 onwards has a new Datatype as DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)
- The .NET Framework includes the **DateTime**, **DateTimeOffset**, and
  **TimeZoneInfo** types, all of which can be used to build applications
  that work with dates and times.
- [Performing Arithmetic Operations with Dates and Times-MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546099.aspx)

Coming back to original question , Using Reflector i have explained the difference in code

```
 public static DateTime Today
    {
      get
      {
        return DateTime.Now.Date;   // It returns the date part of Now

        //Date Property
       // returns same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00) 
      }
    }


    private const long TicksPerMillisecond = 10000L;
    private const long TicksPerDay = 864000000000L;
    private const int MillisPerDay = 86400000;

    public DateTime Date
    {
       get
      {
        long internalTicks = this.InternalTicks; // Date this instance is converted to Ticks 
        return new DateTime((ulong) (internalTicks - internalTicks % 864000000000L) | this.InternalKind);  
// Modulo of TicksPerDay is subtracted - which brings the time to Midnight time 
      }
    }


     public static DateTime Now
        {
          get
          {
           /* this is why I guess Jon Skeet is recommending to use  UtcNow as you can see in one of the above comment*/
            DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;


            /* After this i guess it is Timezone conversion */
            bool isAmbiguousLocalDst = false;
            long ticks1 = TimeZoneInfo.GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc(utcNow, out isAmbiguousLocalDst).Ticks;
            long ticks2 = utcNow.Ticks + ticks1;
            if (ticks2 > 3155378975999999999L)
              return new DateTime(3155378975999999999L, DateTimeKind.Local);
            if (ticks2 < 0L)
              return new DateTime(0L, DateTimeKind.Local);
            else
              return new DateTime(ticks2, DateTimeKind.Local, isAmbiguousLocalDst);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();// gives 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;// gives today date with current time
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;// gives today date and 12:00:00 AM time
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Today` is `DateTime.Now` with time set to zero.

It is important to note that there is a difference between a DateTime value, which represents the number of ticks that have elapsed since midnight of January 1, 0000, and the string representation of that DateTime value, which expresses a date and time value in a culture-specific-specific format: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

`DateTime.Now.Ticks` is the actual time stored by .net (essentially UTC time), the rest are just *representations* (which are important for display purposes).

If the `Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Local` it **implicitly** includes the time zone information of the local computer. When sending over a .net web service, DateTime values are by default serialized with time zone information included, e.g. 2008-10-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00, and a computer in another time zone can still exactly know what time is being referred to.

**So, using DateTime.Now and DateTime.Today is perfectly OK.**

You usually start running into trouble when you begin confusing the string representation with the actual value and try to "fix" the DateTime, when it isn't broken.

Answer (score -1):

`DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` will display only the date part