# In Telerik DatePicker, how do I set the minimum date to equal today?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, datepicker

I tried the code below and it didn't work.  I assume it's a little more involved.

```
@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(o => o.StartDt).Min(new System.DateTime.Now())
```

With Francois' suggestion, I get this error:
[image: Error]

Comment: Did you try the static properties: `DateTime.Now`, or `DateTime.Today`, don't know if that will produce a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to get Today/Now is `DateTime.Today` or `DateTime.Now`.  They aren't constructors, so `new System.DateTime.Today()` will give you the error you're getting.

Use:

`@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(o => o.StartDt).Min(System.DateTime.Today)`

Also, a good answer on the difference between `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Today`: [Difference between System.DateTime.Now and System.DateTime.Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545254/difference-between-system-datetime-now-and-system-datetime-today)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Today()` instead of `Now()`.

```
@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(o => o.StartDt).Min(System.DateTime.Today)
```

EDIT: of course, no need for NEW here :)

Comment: I get a 'property' but is used like type error.  See update.  Thanks.

Comment: This won't work.  `Today` and `Now` are static properties of the `DateTime` class.