# DateTime.Today vs DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, string, datetime, casting

These give me different dates

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime().ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Why? I'm assuming it has something to do with the "time portion" of the datetime, perhaps set to 0-0-0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545254/difference-between-system-datetime-now-and-system-datetime-today

Comment: The first one changes at midnight universal time, that is roughly when it's midnight in London. The second one changes at midnight your time. You might be in a location to the east or west of London, or maybe you use summer time (daylight saving time). Since the two don't change at the same time, there will be periods where they don't agree.

Answer (score 4):

The `DateTime.Today` property actually returns `DateTime.Now.Date`: And it's time segment is looks like `00:00.00000`. And the `DateTime.Now` time segment is looks like `10:09.00000`. So when you are converting to the `ToUniversalTime` it will depends on the current time.

```
public static DateTime Today {
  get {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    return now.Date;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of ToUniversalTime().

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx)

> The Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is equal to the local time minus the UTC offset. For more information about the UTC offset, see [TimeZone.GetUtcOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getutcoffset.aspx). The conversion also takes into account the daylight saving time rule that applies to the time represented by the current DateTime object.