# Cant get hour and minute of the day

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to get the current time:

```
date = "(" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + "-" + 
DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Today.Day.ToString() + " " + 
"(" + DateTime.Today.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Today.Minute.ToString() 
+")" + ")";
```

This should get a date like:

(2013-2-1 (13:01))

But it give me:

(2013-2-1 (0:0))

How can i fix this?

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now`, `DateTime.Today` only gives you the date I think.

Comment: Wow! 3 answers within 26 seconds of each other - 4 if you count the comment above. :-)

Comment: Please use `date = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"(yyyy\-MM\-dd (HH\:mm))")` instead of that.

Comment: Also, not sure why people are downvoting the question. It doesn't seem a bad question to me. It shows a lack of understanding about how DateTimes work, but then all questions show a lack of understanding about something, which is why the question was asked.

Comment: Adding with @ColinMackay, Also care to comment on downvote

Comment: the code excerpt is horrible :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) which is documented as:

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.

So yes, if you find the `Hour` and `Minute` components, they *will* be 0...

If you want the current time of day, use [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) instead. Note that both `Today` and `Now` use the system-local time zone - you need to be sure that that really is what you want to use. (It's probably fine for a local client app, but not for a web app.)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of all the concatenation you are using at the moment, use the DateTime object's ToString() method...

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("(yyyy-M-d (hh:mm))");
```

Also, as pointed out by many others, note the use of `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.Today

The [DateTime.Today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.today%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) has its time part set to 00:00:00
The [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) gets the current date and **time** for the local computer

Answer (score 2):

You have `DateTime.Today` which truncates the time element away.

Use `DateTime.Now` instead which gives you the full date and time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Today`. `DateTime.Today` doesn't include the time, only the date. See also: [Difference between System.DateTime.Now and System.DateTime.Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545254/difference-between-system-datetime-now-and-system-datetime-today)

Answer (score 2):

Use [NodaTime](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) if its a web application. Use `DateTime.Now` for local date and time.

So it should be:

```
date = "(" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + " " + "(" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() +")" + ")";
```

Comment: Calling `DateTime.Now` multiple times is never a good thing.  And Noda Time is awesome, but it is not limited to web applications.  This code doesn't demonstrate Noda Time anyway, so I'm not sure what you were getting at.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this shorter code for current date and time as per your format

`var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("(yyyy-MM-dd(HH:mm))");`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code instead of concatenation. Its much more optimized then the concatenation work you have done.

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("(yyyy-M-d (hh:mm))");
```

Also `DateTime.Today` does not have time element in it.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Today` will return u `2013-2-1 00:00:00` .. It gives the time sure but the timestamp is set to `00:00:00.`. that is the reason why u r not getting an exception n still getting `00:00:00`. Use `DateTime.Now` for current timestamp.