# Range Validator validate that date selected was within the past 3 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-validators

I have a range Validator i use with a jquery calendar select. I want to set the minimum value to be 3 days ago with the maximum value being today (for a valid range of 3 days ago to today). How can I accomplish this?

```
 rvTxtTransactionDateFrom.MinimumValue = // how to set to today - 3 days?
 rvTxtTransactionDateFrom.MaximumValue = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

Comment: I'm confused. What should the min value be? What should the max value be?

Comment: the min value should be anywhere between 3 days ago and today. 
The max value should be no later than today.

Comment: @Indianaadminstopstuck the minimum value is a minimum value... not a range.  The range is the values between minimum and maximum yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
rvTxtTransactionDateFrom.MinimumValue = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3).ToString("MM/dd/yy");
rvTxtTransactionDateFrom.MaximumValue = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rvTxtTransactionDateFrom.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToString("MM/dd/yy");
rvTxtTransactionDateFrom.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

According to the code above, `MinimumValue` is 3 days ago, `MaximumValue` is today.

*EDIT: Out of curiosity between the actual difference between mine and Kritner's answer (`.Now` vs `.Today`) I came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16268210/1017882 which seems well worth a read.*

Comment: Additionally "Now" is the current date and time, "Today" is just today's date (though you're dropping the time due to the ToString either way)