# What is the difference between Today() and Now() in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

Is there a difference between `Today()` and `Now()`?

When I searched online for date expressions I noticed that both are used quite frequently to retreive the same information. Which expression should I be using?

`Today()` and `Now()` in a report:

[image: <code>Today()</code> and <code>Now()</code> in a report]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your example shows, both return today's date, however `Now()` will also include the time when the expression was called. `Today()` will effectively be today at midnight.

[Difference between System.DateTime.Now and System.DateTime.Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545254/difference-between-system-datetime-now-and-system-datetime-today) goes into this in much more depth, though in the .NET context, not specifically SSRS.

Which one should you use? Depends on what you want, as you can see they do two different things. Maybe if you don't care about a time component, use `Today()`, otherwise use `Now()`.