# C# Check given date and time

Tags: c#

Good day everyone. I'm new to C# but I can't seem to understand how DateTime work.
All I wanted to do is to check If a (*givenday*) = today and time is 7pm I wanted to return true. Is this the right way to do it?

Take note *ActionDate* is a field which is inputed by the user.

```
DateTime dateA = Convert.ToDateTime(ActionDate);

int a = dateA.Year;
int b = dateA.Month;
int c = dateA.Day;
int d = timeA.Hour;
int e = timeA.Minute;

var newDate = new DateTime(a, b, c, d, e, 0);

DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(newDate);
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(A);

TimeSpan span = end.Subtract(start);
Decimal minutes = Convert.ToDecimal(span.TotalMinutes);

if 
{
return true;
} else
{
return false;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you convert a DateTime to DateTime?

Comment: Presuming that `ActionDate` is already a `DateTime` this is all you need: `return ActionDate.Date == DateTime.Today && ActionDate.Hour == 19;`. If you want to include the minutes add `&& ActionDate.Minutes == 0`

Comment: Im not sure at all sir. just seing this stackoverflow answer so im trying it out too.

Comment: It work haha thanks Tim took your comment and Nino. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

The way to check if a give date is today and is at 7pm is to use `DateTime.Now`.

Note that `19` is 7pm and `7` is 7am, the `Hour` property uses 24 hour format.

```
bool IsCurrentDayAnd7(DateTime dt) => dt.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && dt.Hour == 19;
```

As  @TimSchmelter commented you could use `DateTime.Today`:

```
bool IsCurrentDayAnd7(DateTime dt) => dt.Date == DateTime.Today && dt.Hour == 19;
```

Comment: Instead of `DateTime.Now.Date` you can use `DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 0):

You have made your code a bit too complicated. First, convert that user input to date, and compate it with current date and time.

```
DateTime dateA = Convert.ToDateTime(ActionDate);
if (dateA.Date == DateTime.Today && dateA.Hour == 19)
{
    //it is current date and hour is 7pm
}
```

Alternatively, check if user's imput is ok, like this:

```
DateTime dateA;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(ActionDate, out dateA))
{
   //alert user that he's entered wrong date 
}
```

EDIT:
as Tim Schmelter noted, code's a bit more readable using `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: Instead of `DateTime.Now.Date` you can use `DateTime.Today`

Comment: If I wanted to make it as 7pm do i only chage it to 19? or 1900?

Comment: 19. I have edited code. If you want to check minutes also, you can do it like this: `if (dateA.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && dateA.Hour == 19 && dateA.Minute == 0)`

Comment: If you want to check the range of Hour properties, the easiest way is to just put your cursor on it, press F1, the MSDN is quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date` property to compare date with current date.

```
if (newDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && newDate.Hour == 19)
{
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `DateTime.Now.Date` you can use `DateTime.Today`

Comment: @TimSchmelter any performance impact or significant difference b/w two ?

Comment: Sure, `Now` and `Date` need to do calculations and create a new instance of `DateTime`. But apart from that it's more readable because you want to compare with `Today`

Comment: @Tim `DateTime.Today` includes hours, minutes and seconds, while `Date` has those values as 0

Comment: @TimSchmelter i agree. Thanks for info.

Comment: @Nino i know that `Date` would have `hours,minutes` as 0 and of course @TimSchmelter knows that.

Comment: @Nino: `DateTime.Today` doesn't "include" hours,minutes,seconds. All are set to 0. So the result is the same as `DateTime.Now.Date` but the intent is clearer and it's also a little bit more efficient to use `Today`.

Comment: @Tim, you're right. I was thinking of `Now`. Sorry.

Comment: It's probably not more efficient since both the [reflector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16247837/529282) and [.NET Source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/DateTime.cs) shows Today merely call Now.Date. However, the readability and intent is far more important than the single calculation for resetting the time.

Comment: @Martheen: true, didn't know