# How set timer for tomorrow 10 AM

Tags: python, datetime, timer, timezone, python-multithreading

I tried some suggestions from other answers to similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031297/940208) and what I have so far is:

```
t = datetime.datetime.today()
tomorrow = datetime.datetime(t.year,t.month,t.day+1,10,0)
```

The problem is, when we have the last day of month this will fail:

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

So how can I rewrite this statement (without wrapping it into IF condition trying to find it this is the last day) to include such situation?

Another question would be - what is a timezone of such timer and how can I work on my current (system) timezone?

Comment: Note: in some timezones `10am tomorrow` might never happen or might happen twice due to DST changes.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - any way to solve this problem?

Comment: yes, multiple (obvious) solutions are possible if you know your context e.g., skip event, repeat event, execute task in a fixed number of seconds, etc.

Comment: My context is "poor-man's cron" - execute some function everyday more or less at 10 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) and [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
tomorrow = t.replace(hour=10, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) + \
           datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Alternatives:

```
tomorrow = datetime.datetime.combine(t.date(), datetime.time(10)) + \
           datetime.timedelta(days=1)

tomorrow = datetime.datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day, 10) + \
           datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```