# What is the difference between python functions `datetime.now()` and `datetime.today()`?

Tags: python, datetime

What is the difference between python functions `datetime.now()` and `datetime.today()` ?

```py
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: datetime.now()

Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 12, 8,28, 909842)

In [3]: datetime.today()

Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 12,8, 45, 175839)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**datetime.datetime.now()** takes tzinfo as keyword argument but **datetime.today()** does not take any keyword arguments.

By default, **now()** executes with **datetime.datetime.now(tz=None)**

As quoted in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now

> **datetime.now()** return the current local date and time. If optional
>   argument tz is None or not specified, this is like today(), but, if
>   possible, supplies more precision than can be gotten from going
>   through a time.time() timestamp (for example, this may be possible on
>   platforms supplying the C gettimeofday() function).

Comment: As an aside, to specify the ET timezone, I use `import datetime.datetime, pytz; datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))`. More details [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/).

Comment: FWIW, it looks like `now()` is faster than `today()`.  On my machine, `now()` averages 213 ns while `today()` averages 653 ns.  This might be insignificant or might not, depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 15):

See the docs for [`datetime.today`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today) and [`datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), specifically this part from the latter link:

> If optional argument tz is None or not specified, this is like today(), but, if possible, supplies more precision than can be gotten from going through a time.time() timestamp (for example, this may be possible on platforms supplying the C gettimeofday() function).

So in your example, both are the same, although specific platforms may provide more precision with `datetime.now`.

Answer (score 5):

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now): `now()` provides an optional timezone, and can give more precision.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there are three similar functions:

- `datetime.now(tz=None)`  Return the current local date and time.
- `datetime.today()`       Return the current local datetime, with `tzinfo` None.
- `datetime.utcnow()`      Return the current UTC date and time, with `tzinfo` None.

The first thing to note is [from the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now):

> This function (`datetime.now()`) is preferred over `datetime.today()` and `datetime.utcnow()`

---

I think there are two reasons:

First in functionality, `datetime.now` can accomplish what `datetime.today` and `datetime.utcnow`, but not vice versa.

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from datetime import timezone
>>>
>>> # datetime.now(tz=None) is equivalent to datetime.today();
>>> # datetime.utcnow() can't do this!
>>> datetime.now(tz=None)  # This is my local time
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 2, 14, 59, 29, 265094)
>>> datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 2, 14, 59, 29, 650280)
>>>
>>> # datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) is equivalent to datetime.utcnow();
>>> # datetime.today() can't do this!
>>> datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 2, 6, 59, 58, 298594, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.utcnow()  # note that `tzinfo` is lost
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 2, 6, 59, 58, 763605)
```

And what's more, note that the `tzinfo` is lost in `datetime.utcnow()`'s output.
Which means you have no chance to know the exact time out of the context.
This is also pointed out [in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow):

> **Warning**: Because naive `datetime` objects are treated by many `datetime` methods
> as local times, it is preferred to use aware datetimes to represent times in UTC.
> As such, the recommended way to create an object representing the current time
> in UTC is by calling `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.