# Wait until specific time

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I'm writing a program that will do something if `now == specific time and day` and wait till that time if is not equal.

I have a `morning`, `evening`, `days` values, which shows start time, end time and today's day. I would like to make a program that check if today is a weekday and specific time (between `morning` and `evening`) if `True` to do something and if even one of these is `False`, gonna wait till that time and after that do something.

I did it with `while loop` but when it starts with `False` value(not in right time) it continue printing `False` even if that time came and value should change to `True` but it shows `True` when I start it in right time.

Here is the code:

```py
import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import sleep

#setting values
now = datetime.datetime.now()
morning = now.replace(hour=9, minute=00, second=0, microsecond=0)
evening = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
days = now.strftime("%A")

#check if time is in range and return True or False
def time_in_range(morning, evening, x):
    if morning <= evening:
        return morning <= x <= evening
    else:
        return morning <= x or x <= evening
timerange = time_in_range(morning, evening, now)

#check if today is weekday
if date.today().weekday() == 0:
    dayz = True
else:
    dayz = False

# If today weekday and time range do something
if dayz == True and timerange == True:
    print("Yes")

while dayz == False or timerange == False:
    sleep(5)
    timerange = time_in_range(morning, evening, now)
    print(timerange) #this printing false even if is right time.
# But it shows True when I turn it on in right time
```

Comment: `sleep(5)` you sure you need 5 secs. accuracy? Also do you really need to wait for the time to come? why not i.e. use cron to launch your script at given time

Comment: Instead of sleeping in a loop, calculate the number of seconds until the beginning of the next time range, and sleep for that many seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sleep until a specific time YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173134/how-to-sleep-until-a-specific-time-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only initialize your `now` variable once and never update its value to the current *now*. You should update the value inside the `while` loop, for example:

```
while dayz == False or timerange == False:
    sleep(5)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in checking just the hours to determine morning and evening as I can see in your code, you can use below snippet:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from time import sleep

morning_hour = 9
evening_hour = 16

while True:
    curr_time = datetime.now()
    print("Current time : {0}".format(curr_time))
    if curr_time.hour < morning_hour or curr_time.hour > evening_hour or not curr_time.isoweekday():
        print("Job start conditions not met. Determining sleep time")
        add_days = 0
        current_day = curr_time.weekday() == 4
        # Add 3 days for fridays to skip Sat/Sun
        if current_day == 4:
            add_days = 3
        # Add 2 days for Saturdays to skip Sunday
        elif current_day == 5:
            add_days = 2
        else:
            add_days = 1
        next_window = (curr_time + timedelta(days=add_days)).replace(hour=9, minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
        delta = next_window - datetime.now()
        print("Sleep secs : {0}".format(delta.seconds))
        sleep(delta.seconds)
    else:
        print("Do something")
        break
```