# Python version of sleep_until

Tags: python, time, sleep

I want to write a Python program that waits some arbitrary time into the future (e.g. the time 500 milliseconds from now) and do something.  I have a C++ code that does this fine using the Chrono library, so how can I do this in Python?  I need accuracy of higher than 50 milliseconds (important) which this C++ code provides.

---

I do not want time.sleep(),  I want a specific time_point in the future to sleep to and not a duration because I want to sync multiple threads to the same time.

```cpp
int main() {
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

      
        // get time 500 ms from now
        steady_clock::time_point next_frame = steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(500);

        std::thread t1{takeImages, next_frame};
        std::thread t2{takeImages, next_frame};

}

void takeImages(steady_clock::time_point next_frame)
{
    
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_frame);
        //do something here

}
```

Comment: Voted to reopen because sleeping until a time point is not the same as sleeping for a time duration.  We (humanity) have known this for several decades.  For example the Ada programming language has long acknowledged and supported this distinction.  A correct answer would acknowledge that python does not natively support sleeping until a time point, but 3rd party python libraries might help.

Comment: The linked duplicate answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031111/in-python-how-can-i-put-a-thread-to-sleep-until-a-specific-time

Comment: Thanks @Gerhard!  _That's_ a duplicate! :-)  I tried to cancel my vote to reopen but there does not seem to be a way to do that.

Comment: @Gerhard I saw that answer but it seems like OP doesn't need <50ms accuracy like me and also seems like the top answer doesn't have anything close to that accuracy..